# Stream file using Cognos SDK

Tags: sdk, cognos-10

I am able to save a report in the archive folder using Cognos SDK.
I am wondering if it is possible to stream that file to a variable instead?

Comment: In this question I was streaming a pdf.  This might help [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335592/cognos-v11-sdk-export-to-pdf/52372141#52372141)

Comment: Thank you, I am looking at a Java solution, the link provided is for C#