# Cognos v11 SDK export to pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, cognos

Does anyone have an example that will generate a report as PDF using the sdk?   The SDK.pdf only has html examples.  I can't figure it out. I'm using a c# controller to call cognos to generate the report.

The runOptionStringArray value must be PDF.

```
outputFormat.value = new string[] { "PDF" };
```

The data i get back from the call looks like this:  "JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MNCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwvTGluZWFyaXplZCAxL0wgICAgIDExOTEyOC9IWyAgICAgICA1ODggICAgICAgIDE2MV0vTyA2L0UgICAgIDExODAzMi9OIDEvVCAgICAgMTE5MDAyPj4KZW5kb2JqCnhyZWYNCjQgMTUNCjAwMDAwMDAwMTYgMDAwMDAgbg0KMDAwMDAwMDc0OSAwMDAwMCBuDQowM"

I've tried this, but it still doesn't render as pdf.

```
asynchReply res = cBIRS.run( reportPath, parameters, runOptions );
// The report is finished, let's fetch the results and save them to a file.
string data = null;
if( res.status == asynchReplyStatusEnum.complete )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < res.details.Length; i++)
    {
        if (res.details[i] is asynchDetailReportOutput)
        {
            data = ( (asynchDetailReportOutput)res.details[i]).outputPages[0];
        }
    }
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create);
    byte[] hunk_data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    fs.Write(hunk_data, 0, hunk_data.Length);
    fs.Close();
}
```

In the end the pdf does have data, but it can't be opened by adobe.

PS.  I've also tried writing out the file without using the UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes and just using System.IO.File.WriteAllText(outputPath,data);   That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
 byte[] hunk_data = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
```

With

```
 byte[] hunk_data = Convert.FromBase64String(data);
```